# How To Get Chess Titans on Windows 8/10

Tags: download-games, windows

I have noticed that the new Windows 8 and 10 do not have my favorite games, specifically Chess Titans. I really want it so, how can I get Chess Titans on my Windows 8/10 PC without getting a Windows 7 or earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to http://winaero.com/blog/get-windows-7-games-for-windows-10/ and follow the instructions there. One thing I do not believe they mentioned is that once you get Mega, and download the file, go to the Mega file in files explorer. From there open the .exe file and continue with the rest of the steps.